# Using multiple conditions in a single if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

In Python I can do something like this, which I think is more clear, than two pairs of conditionals in one statement:

```
if 1 < 2 < 3:
  print 'triple testing?'

else:
  print 'more like triple failing!'
```

without running into any issues, but in C#, it converts the first comparison, `1 < 2` into a `bool` before moving on, so it's throwing an exception `Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'`.

Is there a way to *avoid* adding the second condition, so I don't have to split up the triple condition into two sets of pairs, rather than one 'triple' condition, as I can do in Python?

```
if (1 < 2 & 2 < 3) { ... }
```

edit: An example where I'd use this is to make sure an `int` is between a range of numbers.

```
if ((0 < x) && (x < 10) { ... } //I can already do this
vs
if (0 < x < 10) { ... } //Would rather have something like this
```

Comment: The approach in the second example you have should work fine. If it isn't then you have some other issue (ignoring the fact you are using hard coded values for illustrative purposes and you need to use the right boolean operator).

Comment: @slugster Yeah, it does, but it's less elegant, I feel, than just `1 < 2 < 3`. I am looking for an alternative to the example I ended with. It seems like I was not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of doing `1 < 2 < 3` in C#. However, you could write a quick extension method to mimic it:

```
public static class Test
{
    public static bool IsSorted<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e)
    {
        return e.Zip(e.Skip(1), (a, b) => Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(a, b))
            .All(x => x <= 0);
    }
}

...

if (new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.IsSorted())
{
    // Do something
}
```

If is definitely overkill for 3 numbers but may be useful if there are more values to compare or they are not hard coded.

Comment: +1: nice idea, probably one could improve it giving a predicate as a parameter to an extension method, so that this predicate would have to be applyable to all pairs with indeces (i,i+1)

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov Agreed. LINQ seems to lack a way of creating pairs or tuples of elements and performing an operation on them. Aggregate seems to be almost it but not quite.

Answer (score 6):

Group the condition. Try this,

```
if ((1 < 2) && (2 < 3))
{
   // statements here
}
else
{
   // statements here
}
```

Comment: In this case the grouping/brackets are not required, the OP simply needs to type the full expression.

Comment: +1 for full code block... it's something small but I think it makes it much more readable and helps put the answer in context.

Comment: I was vague, I think, in my question. I was wondering if there was a way to *avoid* doing something like that, and doing something closer to `1 < 2 < 3`, if only for the sake of less typing.

Comment: @slugster I agree, but it's for clarity purposes. what if you have long condition right?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is, you're looking for

```
If ((1 < 2) && (2< 3)) { doWhatever(); }
```

`&&` is the logical AND operator, there is also `||` for logical OR.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I may have not made it clear enough in my original queston. I've mad some edits to that end. Thanks anyways!